# Accessing objects added to the Tkinter root

Tags: python, tkinter

Let's say that I have the following code:

```
root = Tk()
open = Button(self.root, text='Open', command=self.open, state='disabled')
open.pack()
close = Button(self.root, text='Close', command=self.close, state='disabled')
close.pack()
```

I only want to enable the buttons when some action is performed, so I need to access the buttons again later to edit the state variable. Rather than adding the buttons to a separate list and storing that, is there a way of accessing the buttons, or, for that matter, any set of objects that I have attached to the root (Menus, Drop down lists, or whatever), by calling a method on the root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no definitive way to ask the root window for a list of all widgets. You can use `pack_slaves` or `grid_slaves` to get a list of widgets managed by a particular container, but depending on how you write your app that's no guarantee you'll get all the widgets.

You can also use `winfo_children` to get a list of all direct descendants of a widget. If you have a nested hierarchy of widgets (for example, by using frames as intermediary containers for organizational purpose) you may have to do some sort of looping to find a particular widget.

The best and simplest approach is to have your application be an instance of a class. You can then save references to the widgets as attributes of the class. I highly recommend this approach, there's simply no good reason to do it any other way.

For example:

```
class MyApp(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        self.open_button = Button(...)
        self.close_button = Button(...)
        ...
    def OnSomeEvent(self, event):
        if ...:
            self.open_button.configure(state="disabled")
        else:
            self.open_button.configure(state="normal")
```

Comment: I'm using a class based structure in my application, but I'm just wary of having more references to objects than are necessary. From this and the other responses it seems like the thing that I would ideally have liked (something like self.root.getbuttons()) doesn't exist, and so if storing references to the objects in the class is the most common way of doing things, then I guess I'll stick to that method.

Comment: @heuristicus: storing references is the most common method. You don't need to store references to _all_ widgets though, just the ones you plan on accessing after initialization.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the pack method you can use the pack_slaves method to find items added.  So to iterate over them you can do something like,

```
for item in root.pack_slaves():
    item.do_stuff()
```

Answer (score 0):

These will be in the root's children dictionary, but with a long int (the value of the pointer in the C layer I believe) as the key. (with newlines added in the dict value for readability)

```
>  >>> from Tkinter import Tk, Button
>  >>> root=Tk()
>  >>> open=Button(root, text='Open')
>  >>> root.__dict__
>  {'_tclCommands': ['tkerror', 'exit', '3077241668Ldestroy'],
>     'master': None,
>     'children': {'3077328108L': <Tkinter.Button instance at 0xb76c4cec\>},
>     '_tkloaded': 1,
>     'tk': <tkapp object at 0xb76bd560\>}
```