# GUI Tkinter method which returns a list of all the widgets currently packed with .pack()?

Tags: user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

Is there a method in Tkinter (Python 3.2) which returns a list of all the widgets currently packed with .pack()?

I can't find anything in the documentation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a method exactly for this. Which is called [pack_slaves()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm#Tkinter.Pack.pack_slaves-method)

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

button = tk.Button(root, text="this is button")
label = tk.Label(root, text="this is label")

button.pack()
label.pack()

slaves = root.pack_slaves()
print (slaves)

root.mainloop()
```

This is output

```
>>> [<tkinter.Button object at 0x000000000325E160>, <tkinter.Label object at 0x000000000322C160>]
```

Also you might want to check this question. [Accessing objects added to the Tkinter root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879781/accessing-objects-added-to-the-tkinter-root)